# Programmatically maintained email filter software that works with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: windows, linux, email

Up to now, the company I work for has used the [Cyrus](https://cyrusimap.org/) mail system, which comes with built-in support for [Sieve](http://cyrusimap.org/mediawiki/index.php/Cyrus_Sieve).

I love the way this software works. Its main feature is that it allows me to manage my own Sieve scripts.  Basically, I have written some software that analyzes my own activities and interactions in real-time and generates a new Sieve script that is uploaded to the Cyrus server every hour by *cron*.  This script automatically prioritizes incoming mail so that mail from the people I am currently engaged with gets top priority, while less urgent messages are pushed down in the queue (no matter how many "Urgent" and exclamation marks the *sender* has used to get my attention).

Now, the company I work for has decommissioned "Cyrus" and switched to something called "Microsoft Exchange".  IMHO, it is a poorly documented and poorly implemented piece of cruft. Unfortunately, nobody cares about my opinion, so I *must* use it (or find some other employer).

I am understand that there are clients for Microsoft Exchange (like *Outlook*) with some built-in filtering capability that allow the user to maintain mail filters using a GUI. I am not interested in that.

What I am looking for, is a way to maintain an Microsoft Exchange email filter  programmatically.

Something that runs on Gnu/Linux will be preferred, but I will also consider Windows-based solutions.

My main requirement is something that I can manage by a program/process (not a GUI), and that it is capable of communicating filtering instructions to "Microsoft Exchange" (by means of an API or any other possible interface including file upload).

If I could continue to use *Sieve* as the filtering language, that would be great (but I understand that there is not much hope for that).  I am prepared to learn a new language (including *Visual BASIC*) if that it takes to accomplish this. *Sieve* support is by no means a requirement for an acceptable answer.